How to pass array in parameter in oracle
Can someone tell me what is wrong with this I get the message that p_var must be declare
I need to pass an array of data inside a list of parameter
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PKG 
IS
type rec_type is RECORD
(
    p_var1              varchar2(1),
    p_var2              varchar2(2)
);
    type rec_array is varray(50) of rec_type;

PROCEDURE TEST_PROC (
    p_proc1     IN VARCHAR2,
    p_proc2     IN VARCHAR2,
    p_var_type  IN rec_array      
);

END TEST_PKG;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SICMA."TEST_PKG" 
IS
   PROCEDURE TEST_PROC (
    p_proc1            IN VARCHAR2,
    p_proc2            IN VARCHAR2,
    p_var_type         IN rec_array      
   )
IS
v_nombre      NUMBER;
v_var1        VARCHAR2(2);
v_var2        VARCHAR2(2);

BEGIN
v_nombre := 2;
        FOR i IN 1 .. v_nombre
        LOOP
            v_var1   := p_var_type.p_var1(i);
            v_var2   := p_var_type.p_var2(i);
        END LOOP;            
        
        dbms_output.putline('v_var1' || v_var1);
        dbms_output.putline('v_var2' || v_var2);
   END TEST_PROC;
END TEST_PKG;
/         


To be able to compile without error

Your indexing into the array is in the wrong place; you want to refer to the field within the nth element of the array, so instead of:
            v_var1   := p_var_type.p_var1(i);
            v_var2   := p_var_type.p_var2(i);

it should be:
            v_var1   := p_var_type(i).p_var1;
            v_var2   := p_var_type(i).p_var2;

Your dbms_output call is also wrong, and at the moment you're looking at exactly two array entries - which will fail if there are fewer - and only actually doing anything with the second.
You might want something more like:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PKG
IS
  PROCEDURE TEST_PROC (
    p_proc1       IN VARCHAR2,
    p_proc2       IN VARCHAR2,
    p_var_type    IN rec_array      
  )
  IS
    v_var1        VARCHAR2(1);
    v_var2        VARCHAR2(2);
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. p_var_type.count
    LOOP
      v_var1 := p_var_type(i).p_var1;
      v_var2 := p_var_type(i).p_var2;

      dbms_output.put_line('v_var1: ' || v_var1);
      dbms_output.put_line('v_var2: ' || v_var2);
    END LOOP;            
        
  END TEST_PROC;
END TEST_PKG;
/

which will loop over all of the elements (via count). You don't currently really need the local variables, but presumably you will be doing something with those that is easier than just always referring directly to the array element and its fields directly.
fiddle
